# Transfer data to MySQL server with PHP when using javascript to generate input fields

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

Here I have a webpage with a small sample table containing three columns.  I have a button which will add another row, identical to the current row with the input fields using javascript.  I would like to be able to add as many rows as I like (ex: 5 rows), hit submit, and have the data in the input fields be put into a MySQL table using PHP.  How might I accomplish this?

I know how to transfer data from input fields to MySQL using PHP, I just don't how to do it when I add X number of rows with javascript.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function addRow() {
      var myTable = document.getElementById('myTable');
      var currentIndex = myTable.rows.length;
      var currentRow = myTable.insertRow(-1);

      var Column1box = document.createElement('input');
      Column1box.setAttribute("name", "Column1box" + currentIndex);

      var Column2box = document.createElement('input');
      Column2box.setAttribute("name", "Column2box" + currentIndex);

      var Column3box = document.createElement('input');
      Column3box.setAttribute("name", "Column3box" + currentIndex);

      var currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
      currentCell.appendChild(Column1box);

      currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
      currentCell.appendChild(Column2box);

      currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
      currentCell.appendChild(Column3box);
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <table id="myTable">
    <tr>
      <td>Column 1</td>
      <td>Column 2</td>
      <td>Column 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="text1"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="text2"></td>
      <td><input type="text" name="text3"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <button type="button" name="addRow" onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
  <button type="submit" onclick"put in php table">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is code from a regular webpage where I put data into a MySQL table.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form class="" action="action.php" method="POST">
    <table id="myTable">
      <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td>
        <td>Column 2</td>
        <td>Column 3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="text1"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="text2"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="text3"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>

  <button type="button" name="addRow" onclick="addRow()">Add Row</button>
  <button type="submit" onclick"put in php table">Submit</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is action.php where dbh.inc.php is a database connection.

```
<?php 

mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

include_once 'dbh.inc.php';

$input1 = $_POST['text1'];
$input2 = $_POST['text2'];
$input3 = $_POST['text3'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO MySQL_Table (Column1, Column2, Column3)
        VALUES ('$input1', '$input2', '$input3');";
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

header("Location: ../index.php?log=success");
```

Comment: You can use arrays for your inputs, then the `$_POST` variables will be arrays as well: `<input type="text" name="text[]">`. That will make processing on the server a lot easier.

Comment: Do you have code where a regular webpage adds data to your database?

Comment: @Forbs I added my code where a regular webpage adds data to my database.